Algorithm Analysis Help
I would like help understanding this slide from my class, especially the inner loop part. I do not understand how he is getting at n - (n - 1 - 1) = 2
I do understand that when j = n - 1 we get n - (n - 1) but I don't get why we have an extra -1 there.
I'd appreciate if anyone could walk through their thought process for this, thank you!


Beware typos in the slide. For starters, there is one in 2.…for i = (j+1)…. Suggest using a font where the glyphs for $I, l$
and $1$ can be told from each other.

The n comparisons from 1. can only be comparing the control variable to the limit.
The $t_i$s are really $n - j + 1$ (+1 for the comparison of the control variable to the limit):
$n - (n-1) + 1$ for $j=n-1$.

thank you so much!!
